# R parallel foreach loop. Error in { : task failed - "argument is of length zero

Tags: r, loops, foreach, parallel-processing

Hello stack overflow community,

My issue is as follows,

I am running a foreach loop in parallel with 8 cores. However, whenever I have the loop running over more tasks than those 8 cores I get **Error in { : task 9 failed - "argument is of length zero"** for just the tasks that overflow the number of cores. I can use trycatch{} but then I do not receive the outcome from those overflowing tasks on top of the 8 cores, in this case.

A piece of the real code is as follows (the functions are too lengthy to paste them here):

```
cl <- makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)
sys.time = Sys.time()
CTN_concept = c("personality", "performance", "quant", "setups", "fundamentals", "filters")

    result = foreach (i = 1:length(what2update.symbol), .combine = 'rbind', .inorder = F,) %dopar% { 

    some_functions = function(x) {}
    library(some_libraries)

symbol = what2update.symbol[i]
scan = scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),] # CHANGE
name = scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), "name"]
prices.d = prices.d.list[[symbol]]
prices.d2 = prices.d
prices.d2$logret = dailyReturn(prices.d, type = "log")
prices.wk = to.weekly(prices.d)
prices.wk2 = prices.wk
prices.wk2$logret = weeklyReturn(prices.d, type = "log")

if ( !(grepl("^", symbol, fixed = T) | symbol %in% commodities$ticker | symbol %in% currencies$ticker) ) {

  if (is.null(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"PMT_update.date"]) | is.null(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"PMT_update.date"]) | is.na(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"PMT_update.date"])) {
    PMT = PMT.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), PMT.vector] = PMT
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"PMT_update.date"] = sys.time
  }

  if ( "all" %in% CTN_concept
       & scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"all_update.date"] < Sys.Date() | is.null(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"all_update.date"]) | is.na(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"all_update.date"])
  ) {

    personality = personality.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), personality.vector] = personality
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"personality_update.date"] = sys.time

    performance = performance.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), performance.vector] = performance
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"performance_update.date"] = sys.time

    setups = setups.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), setups.vector] = setups
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"setups_update.date"] = sys.time

    quant = quant.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), quant.vector] = quant
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"quant_update.date"] = sys.time

    fundamentals = fundamentals.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), fundamentals.vector] = fundamentals
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"fundamentals_update.date"] = sys.time

    filters = filters.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), filters.vector] = filters
    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"filters_update.date"] = sys.time

    scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"all_update.date"] = sys.time

  } else {

    if ( "personality" %in% CTN_concept
         & scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"personality_update.date"] < Sys.Date() | is.null(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"personality_update.date"]) | is.na(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"personality_update.date"])
    ) {
      personality = personality.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), personality.vector] = personality
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"personality_update.date"] = sys.time
    }
    if ( "performance" %in% CTN_concept
         & scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"performance_update.date"] < Sys.Date() | is.null(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"performance_update.date"]) | is.na(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"performance_update.date"])
    ) {
      performance = performance.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), performance.vector] = performance
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"performance_update.date"] = sys.time
    }
    if ( "setups" %in% CTN_concept
         & scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"setups_update.date"] < Sys.Date() | is.null(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"setups_update.date"]) | is.na(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"setups_update.date"])
    ) {
      setups = setups.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), setups.vector] = setups
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"setups_update.date"] = sys.time
    }
    if ( "quant" %in% CTN_concept
         & scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"quant_update.date"] < Sys.Date() | is.null(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"quant_update.date"]) | is.na(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"quant_update.date"])
    ) {
      quant = quant.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), quant.vector] = quant
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"quant_update.date"] = sys.time
    }
    if ( "fundamentals" %in% CTN_concept
         & scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"fundamentals_update.date"] < Sys.Date() | is.null(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"fundamentals_update.date"]) | is.na(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"fundamentals_update.date"])
    ) {
      fundamentals = fundamentals.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), fundamentals.vector] = fundamentals
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"fundamentals_update.date"] = sys.time
    }
    if ( "filters" %in% CTN_concept
         & scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"filters_update.date"] < Sys.Date() | is.null(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"filters_update.date"]) | is.na(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"filters_update.date"])
      ) {
      filters = filters.function(symbol, name, prices.d, prices.wk, prices.d2, prices.wk2)
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol), filters.vector] = filters
      scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),"filters_update.date"] = sys.time
    }
  }

} else { scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),] }



return(scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),])

} #, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), paste(i, "i CTN.function", symbol, sep = " | "), "\n")}) } # for

    stopCluster(cl)
```

In sum, if I set the number of elements in *what2update.symbol* to be fewer than the number of cores, the code runs seamlessly. Set 1 core fewer than the number of elements in that vector and the Error in { : task 9 failed - "argument is of length zero" (for 8 cores and 9 elements in vector *what2update.symbol* shows up). Don't you think is there anything we can do something about it?

Comment: Many R functions will fail with arguments of length 0. The `if` function is a common source of that error. Your obviously not-real code is of no use in allowing us to gain any inkling of the root causes.

Comment: The point is that whenever I set the number of cores to be higher or equal to the number of tasks, in this case: length(what2update.symbol), the code runs seamlessly and I obtain the desired results. In my next comment, I attach the main part of the code. Alas, the functions are too lengthy to copy them here.

Comment: Try running it with %do% and see if it works not in parallel.

Comment: I solved the problem. My problem was that I assumed that the code ran properly on "for" since I was running exactly the same code on another script with the only difference that this code had the added line "scan = scan[which(scan$ticker == symbol),] # CHANGE", which was stealing next iterations of the loop (ie. those taken on new cores whenever any new was available) from the data frame base. Thanks Kreuni for inspiring me to check the obvious first. Good lesson.